# $f: \mathbb R \to L(F)$. Prove that it is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \to L(F)$, where $F$ is a normed vector space, and $L(F)$ denotes the space of continuous linear mappings from $F$ to $F$, be differentiable at $0$ with $f(0) = id_F$, i.e. $f(0)(x) = x$ for all $x \in F$. Moreover, suppose that $f(t+r) = f(t) \circ f(r)$, for all $r,t \in \mathbb R$.

Prove that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

I just want to know why $f$ is even differentiable on $\mathbb R$. I'll write down what I thought about and some things that I noticed.

$f$ being differentiable at $0$, we have:

$$\lim_{t \to 0} t^{-1} (f(t) - id_F)$$

exists, i.e. it is a well-defined linear mapping. So far, I couldn't see how this helps.

By $f(t+r) = f(t) \circ f(r)$, for all $r,t \in \mathbb R$, we get that $f(t)$ is invertible for all $t \in \mathbb R$, and its inverse map is $f(-t)$ (so far not helpful).

Basically, we want to prove: $\forall t_0 \in \mathbb R$,

$$\lim_{t \to t_0} (t-t_0)^{-1} (f(t) -f(t_0))$$

is a well-defined mapping (afterwards, that it is linear). Right?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiability everywhere follows from differentiability at zero, as follows:

For every $t,h\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}=\frac{f(t)\circ f(h)-f(t)}{h}=f(t)\circ \frac{f(h)-id}{h}=f(t)\circ \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$

Fix $t$ and let $h\to 0$, and the right hand side will tend to $f(t)\circ id=f(t)$, which is what you expect: the derivative of a linear transformation (and such is $f(t)$) -- is equal to itself.

Comment: But the RHS doesn't actually tend to that expression. It's $f(0)$ that is $id_F$, not $f'(0)$.

Comment: However that doesn't change much. I got the trick. Thanks.